# How to assign predefined tags to customer complaints

Tags: machine-learning, tags, nlp

I have a problem in natural language processing:

I want to assign tags to customer complaints. For every complaint, it needs to be possible to assign several tags.

For example:
'Your food and service is terrible'
- I would want to assign the tags 'food' and 'service'

I have a dataset to which I can assign tags manually for every tag and line.

I could run seperate logistic regressions to assign a likelihood for every line and tag based on word count.

Is there a better approach?

I know I could do LDA, but I find it a bit weird that I would have to predefine the number of topics.

Thanks,
Felix